# Eclipse Plugin Export

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jaspersoft-studio

I have a problem.

Currently, on my PC I have Eclipse 2022-12 installed, where I have the Jaspersoft Studio 6.20 plugin installed to be able to develop reports directly from eclipse.

I bought a new PC, and I installed Eclipse 2023-12, when I went to install all the plugins that I already had in the previous version (I made a new installation), I was surprised that Jaspersoft Studio is no longer there available, neither in the eclipse marketplace, nor in sourceforge, and I can't find the zip of the plugin anywhere (I think something has happened with its licensing, and they have removed all downloads)

I am therefore trying to export the plugin that I already have installed on my old PC, and import it into the new one, that is, somehow obtain the .zip that I already have installed on my PC.

Is there a way to do this?

I have reviewed how eclipse folders work

I have seen that in .p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache the .jars of various libraries that you install are stored. But I can't find the one from jasperreports

I have also tried with the eclipse functions, that is: File / Export / Install / Installed Software Items to file, but it only exports the metadata, and then to import it tries to download from the repositories, where my plugin no longer exists.

I have located the jaspersoft studio .jar in .p2\pool\plugins , but I have not been able to do anything with them

Comment: Does in the Eclipse of your new PC _File > Install > From Existing Installation_ and using (a copy of) the installation directory of your old Eclipse work?